# What is the Delphi equivalent of C#'s PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, delphi, propertygrid, equivalent

Is there a Delphi equivalent to C#'s `PropertyGrid`? I want to implement something similar to the Object Inspector in RAD Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi has TValueListEditor, but it's extremely simple, nowhere near the functionality of the object inspector. For that you need a 3rd party control. [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org) has a capable, free inspector component, and there are many commercial ones, such as [Inspex](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/Inspex) from Raize Software and [VerticalGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExVerticalGrid/) from Developer Express. VerticalGrid comes in several variants, one of which acts as an object inspector - all you need to do is assign an instance to a property, and the component does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

While I havent checked out the pricing I would also investigate TMS software. I know they have a property-editor that is just as advanced as Developer Express - but TMS are usually more reasonable when it comes to price than Developer Express.

You could also take a quick search as www.Koder.com and see if you come across some opensource alternatives there. Personally I went for TMS.